# Facebook Login on Meteor works on Chrome only

Tags: facebook, authentication, localhost, meteor

I'm facing with an issue using Facebook Login in Meteor. It seems to work correctly with Chrome (desktop) only.

I'm in a **localhost:3000** environment, I set up Facebook App in the right way, I saved App Id and App Secret in the **Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert();** server-side, Login button appears correctly but... It only works on Chrome (desktop).

Using Firefox, Safari and mobile browsers like Chrome or Safari for iOS, this is what my server console produces in output:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook. failed [400] {"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
at getTokenResponse (app/packages/accounts-facebook/facebook_server.js:71:11)
at Object.handleOauthRequest (app/packages/accounts-facebook/facebook_server.js:17:18)
at Object.Accounts.oauth2._handleRequest (app/packages/accounts-oauth2-helper/oauth2_server.js:9:31)
at Object.Accounts.oauth._middleware (app/packages/accounts-oauth-helper/oauth_server.js:122:23)
at app/packages/accounts-oauth-helper/oauth_server.js:95:22
```

I cleaned the cache too but without any result.
"Internal server error" and a button "Dismiss" is the output.

Comment: It wouldn't work on mobile browsers (because the redirect is to localhost which is invalid there). I can't seem to reproduce this for safari & firefox. Are you using the accounts-ui package or doing facebook log ins yourself?

Comment: Remove all users from mongo and try again in Chrome.